# How do I remove a particular string from a JSON file(or Array). Not a value or a key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this code and I want to remove all the "px" string from the document.

```
 myArray = [
  {
    matching: true,
    selector: "tag:img +  id:mainImage + className:none",
    location: {
      height: "1669.16px",
      width: "659px",
      margin: "20px",
      padding: "10px"
    },
    image_src: [],
  },
];
```

```js
    var myArray = [
      {
        matching: true,
        selector: "tag:img +  id:mainImage + className:none",
        location: {
          height: "1669.16px",
          width: "659px",
          margin: "20px",
          padding: "10px"
        },
        image_src: [],
      },
    ];
    
    console.log(myArray);
    
    var newArray = myArray.filter(e => e !== 'px')
    console.log(newArray);
```

I will have more than 5000 lines of this code so I want to remove it automatically.
The problem is that I don't want to remove a key or value or an array item but a specific string that is integrated in a value.

This is a file that is created with an array. I push these properties to the array and download it as a json file.

I have tried:

```
arr.replace("px", "")
```

I have tried to splice it but I couldn't cause it is made with an array but not an array anymore.

Comment: `.replace(/px/,'')` ?

Comment: If it’s in a file how about doing sed once? “sed ’s/\([0-9]+\)px/\1/g’ < file-in.txt > file-out.txt

Comment: @gorak I tried it. Doesn't work.

Comment: With the help of JSON.stringify you can walk you entire object and replace its values: `const res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj, (_, v) => typeof v === "string" ? v.replace(/px$/, '') : v));` - note: this will remove any key-value pairs that have a value of `undefined`

Comment: @NickParsons It worked! Thanks! Is this regex? /px$/ 
I have tried this with "px" but it didn't work.

Comment: @sunflowerseed great :). Yeah `/px$/` is regex. It means match any `"px"` at the end ($) of a string and replace it. Using just `"px"` should also work though

Comment: @NickParsons Noted! Gotta learn that. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) you can get it to recursively traverse your entire object and replace its values using the [replacer parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter). The replace method below uses the regular expression `/px$/` which is used to match and replace any strings that end with `px` with an empty string:

```js
const arr = [{ matching: true, selector: "tag:img +  id:mainImage + className:none", location: { height: "1669.16px", width: "659px", margin: "20px", padding: "10px" }, image_src: [], }, ];

const res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr, (_, v) => typeof v === "string" ? v.replace(/px$/, '') : v));
console.log(res);
```

**Note**: This will remove any key-value pairs that have a value of `undefined`